# Upgrading via Terminal from LinuxMint 18.3 to 19.3--How much disk space?

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, upgrade, disk-usage, cinnamon

I would like to know how much space I need to upgrade from 18.3 to 19.3...it reads 1500 MB necessary to download and 1600 MB of additional disk space will be used. Are the 1500 MB already extracted, or will it extract those 1500 MB to like 3000 MB and then only delete the original downloaded files? or does it immediately and directly install the 1500 MB of files on the disk without unpacking, so that the end up being 1600 MBs then?

Comment: The initial install is a compressed archive so you can expect 3-4GB disk space to be used.  As a rule of thumb, you can expect the newer distro taking ~1GB more than the old one.  Depending on what do you intend to do with your computer, I'd recommend to ensure you have much more free space than that.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, so the downloaded 1,5 gb will be xtracted to around 3 to 4 gb correct? and then the total installation y get installed and take up around 15 or so gb on the disk, correct?

Comment: and can you tell me please how I can get ATI/AMD drivers for ubuntu 16.04.01, which is the base for Linux Mint 18.3?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about AMD drivers.  But please ask another question for a different topic, and tell what is your exact graphics card!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you install on your computer.  I don't know mint, but I have seen fresh recent ubuntu install that takes ~4GB.  This This was a minimum standard install though, and everything else you add there quickly fills up your harddisk. So if you just download and install, it would not take 15GB, but if you install/update the software you use, you quite likely end up using this much. E.g. a recent ubuntu 20 fills 13GB, and an older ubuntu 18 fills 26GB.  Note though that these are not just the files that are copied from the repos, but also various kind of runtime and temporary files.

How much free space do you need also depends on how do you partition the the disk, and what do you do with your computer.  In particular, where are `/var` and `/tmp`, and what will be stored there.  Assuming your `/var` and `/tmp` are on the system partition `/`, and this is separate from `/home`, I'd say 5GB is the absolute minimum for something like a desktop system (but special installations may be much smaller).  To be on safe side, I'd say reserve at least 25GB for your system partition, better if >=50GB.  But again, it depends on what you do and how do you organize your hard disk.